# load view inside view in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

Actually m using ahref with onclick function inside my view

```
<a href="<? echo base_url();?>index.php/manager/engineer" onclick=window.open("<? echo base_url();?>index.php/manager/engineer") >
```

it is redirecting to url correctly

```
http://localhost:8888/CI/index.php/manager/engineer
```

but in that page m getting error as

```
The page you requested was not found.
```

even though i have created engineers view file

Anyone helping me to find the solution will be needfull

Comment: are you having the view that you have specifed?

Comment: can you post the controller code of this page http://localhost:8888/CI/index.php/manager/engineer

Comment: I think this is not load view inside a view , this is page redirection when a link is clicked , i think the error is in your URL , are you sure is this the correct url

Comment: It simply means you don't have `engineer` function in `manager` `controller` .

Answer (score 1):

the CI router just run external links of controller classes and you can't load views externally. instead on you can load views internally on your controllers and now open the controller address via your browsers.
see more : http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html